# How Hibernate to query three tables in a time?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have three tables :

```
 1. org,
 2. product_info 
 3. service_info.
```

And, table `product_info` is mapping table `service_info` `ManyToMany`,

means,many `products` mapping many `services`.

While,table `org` is mapping table `product_info OneToMany`,

means,one `org` have `many products`.

When I initialize my web

[image]

I want to view the `org` table's `column`. How to do ?
Under classes are the persistent classes for three tables.

**ProductService class**:
`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product_service")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)

public class ProductService  implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 private String id;
 private ServiceInfo serviceInfo;//this is the service table
 private String parammapping;
 private ProductInfo productInfo;//this is the product table


// Constructors

/** default constructor */
public ProductService() {
}

/** minimal constructor */
public ProductService(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}



// Property accessors
@Id   
@Column(name="ID", unique=true, nullable=false, length=50)
public String getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="SERVICEID")
public ServiceInfo getServiceInfo() {
    return this.serviceInfo;
}

public void setServiceInfo(ServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
    this.serviceInfo = serviceInfo;
}


@Column(name="PARAMMAPPING", length=1000)
public String getParammapping() {
    return parammapping;
}

public void setParammapping(String parammapping) {
    this.parammapping = parammapping;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="PRODUCTID")
public ProductInfo getProductInfo() {
    return this.productInfo;
}

public void setProductInfo(ProductInfo productInfo) {
    this.productInfo = productInfo;
}
```

}`

**baseOrg class**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="base_org")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class BaseOrg  implements java.io.Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 private String id;
 private String code;
 private String name;

private List<BaseRuleEngineLog> serviceUsedLogs = new ArrayList<BaseRuleEngineLog>(0);
 private List<ProductInfo> productInfos = new ArrayList<ProductInfo>(0);
 private List<BaseCreditQuery> baseCreditQueries = new ArrayList<BaseCreditQuery>(0);

// Constructors

/** default constructor */
public BaseOrg() {
}

/** minimal constructor */
public BaseOrg(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Id 
@Column(name="ID", unique=true, nullable=false, length=50)
public String getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name="CODE", length=50)

public String getCode() {
    return this.code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

@Column(name="NAME", length=200)

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="baseOrg")
public List<BaseRuleEngineLog> getServiceUsedLogs() {
    return this.serviceUsedLogs;
}

public void setServiceUsedLogs(List<BaseRuleEngineLog> serviceUsedLogs) {
    this.serviceUsedLogs = serviceUsedLogs;
}
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="baseOrg")
public List<ProductInfo> getProductInfos() {
    return this.productInfos;
}

public void setProductInfos(List<ProductInfo> productInfos) {
    this.productInfos = productInfos;
}
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="baseOrg")
public List<BaseCreditQuery> getBaseCreditQueries() {
    return this.baseCreditQueries;
}

public void setBaseCreditQueries(List<BaseCreditQuery> baseCreditQueries) {
    this.baseCreditQueries = baseCreditQueries;
}
```

}

**productInfo class**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product_info")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class ProductInfo  implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String id;
 private BaseOrg baseOrg;//baseOrg table
 private String code;
 private String name;
 private String orgcode;

 private List<ProductService> productServices = new ArrayList<ProductService>(0);


// Constructors

/** default constructor */
public ProductInfo() {
}

/** minimal constructor */
public ProductInfo(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}



// Property accessors
@Id 
@Column(name="ID", unique=true, nullable=false, length=50)
public String getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ORGID")
public BaseOrg getBaseOrg() {
    return this.baseOrg;
}

public void setBaseOrg(BaseOrg baseOrg) {
    this.baseOrg = baseOrg;
}

@Column(name="CODE", length=100)
public String getCode() {
    return this.code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

@Column(name="NAME", length=100)
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


@Column(name="ORGCODE", length=100)
public String getOrgcode() {
    return this.orgcode;
}

public void setOrgcode(String orgcode) {
    this.orgcode = orgcode;
}
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="productInfo")
public List<ProductService> getProductServices() {
    return this.productServices;
}

public void setProductServices(List<ProductService> productServices) {
    this.productServices = productServices;
}
```

}

**serviceInfo class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="service_info")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class ServiceInfo  implements java.io.Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String id;
 private String name;
 private String code;
 private List<ProductService> productServices = new ArrayList<ProductService>(0);

// Constructors

/** default constructor */
public ServiceInfo() {
}

/** minimal constructor */
public ServiceInfo(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

// Property accessors
@Id 
@Column(name="ID", unique=true, nullable=false, length=50)
public String getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}


@Column(name="NAME", length=100)
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name="CODE", length=100)
public String getCode() {
    return this.code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}


@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="serviceInfo")
public List<ProductService> getProductServices() {
    return this.productServices;
}

public void setProductServices(List<ProductService> productServices) {
    this.productServices = productServices;
}
```

}
[product_service table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bobfL.png)

*Thank you for forgiving my poor English,this is my first time questioning on Stack Overflow.*

Comment: Please, add your persistent classes.

Comment: Hibernate does not query tables, it queries entities.

Comment: if possible post your entity classes...

Comment: OK,OK.I have posted my persistent classes.thank you,guys

Answer (score 0):

OK,I resolve it.
i found its so sample,lol.
Because,most criteria have been packaged.At the first time ,I want to use the HQL to resolve it,but in vain.I just add this sentences,and getted it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuL6k.png)